# Nested fragment still being visible when tab change

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, visible

I have an activity with a tab view which have two fragments(A and B). Fragments A have a frameLayout with a nested fragment C.

When changed C to D and then change to another tab item, the method "isVisible" of fragment D is still returning Visible, so the action menu is visible.

I thoungt in this solution:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    boolean v = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition() == 0; 
    menu.findItem(R.id.act_search).setVisible(v);
}
```

but it is the worse solution of the world xd

Comment: The problem was simple. I was adding the fragment insted of replacing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that frameLayout displays a single view,  views added to a frameLayout are placed at the top left of the layout and any other view added to the frameLayout will overlap the View that came before. 
So try using another layout and see if the problem persists.

Comment: It doesn't work. Fragment C is replaced by Fragment D, but when a change the tab view (scrolling it) to Fragment B, the icons in action bar of Fragment D doesn't desappiar. I check the "isVisible" method of Fragment D and it's still returning true.

Comment: I think that Fragment D is still visible on Fragment A but it is not visible on Screen. Can it posible?

Comment: isVisible should tell if it is visible on screen, could you share some of the code? are you using a view pager with the fragments?